# How to integrate QR code reader in my own app.?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, qr-code, zxing

I'm developing an app in which I need to add QR code reader feature, which should be some thing like this, I need to have a icon on homepage and by clicking that icon `QR reader` should work. I googled it and found that ZBarCoderReader is good to use but I got stuck in integrating this SDK. Can anyone help integrating this SDK. i know i have to use below links for integrating this SDK.
http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/install.html
http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/camera.html

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **1.** Download the ZBar SDK from this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/iPhoneSDK/ZBarSDK-1.2.dmg/download)
- **2.** Open the `dmg` and copy the `ZBarSDK` folder to your `project directory`.
- **3.** In XCode right click on your project and select "Add Files to yourprojectname" and add the `ZBarSDK framework`.
- **4.** Now go to the `Build Phases` and expand `Link Binary With Libraries` and add the following additional frameworks

  - **AVFoundation.framework**
  - **CoreMedia.framework**
  - **CoreVideo.framework**
  - **QuartzCore.framework**
  - **libiconv.dylib**

Then

**Import the header file**

```
#import "ZBarSDK.h"
```

On the icon button's touch add the following code:

```
- (IBAction)iconButtonTouchEvent:(id)sender {

    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

    //Hide Info Button at Right bottom and Show only Cancel Button at Left Bottom
    float currentVersion= 5.1;
    float sysVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue];

    UIView * infoButton;
    if (sysVersion > currentVersion) {
        infoButton = [[[[[reader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:3];
     }
     else {
        infoButton = [[[[[reader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:2];
     }
    [infoButton setHidden:YES];

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 0];

    [self presentModalViewController: reader animated: YES];
}

#pragma mark - Barcode Delegate Methods

- (void)imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info{

    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];

    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;

    for(symbol in results)
        break;

    NSLog(@"Barcode Data = %@", symbol.data);

    [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

[**Sample project**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ka59kt2666d2a1d/BarcodeDemo.zip)

Comment: I'm trying to import the header but i don't know why it says this file doesn't exist. I'm importing this header in my app-prefix.pch file.

Comment: @Zac24 Did you download the ZBar SDK? and added it in your project

Comment: ya i have downloaded and i can see the file there in my project.

Comment: there also the same Problem that's why i tried to import in Prefix.pch .

Comment: everything looks fine with your answer but i don't know i have tried multiple times but still when i'm importing the file. It says file 'ZBarSDK.h'fle not found.?

Comment: @Zac24 Did you run the sample project?.

Comment: ya. i checked and run the sample..

Comment: some how i made it work but can u just tell me that on what all devices it will work, coz i tried to check with my iPod 4th generation n pressed the cancel button, it crashed. 

[HomeViewController imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ddd91e0
2013-06-23 16:22:20.852 MyappName[154:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HomeViewController imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ddd91e0'

Comment: @Zac24 If you find the above solution correct or helpful please "up-vote" and "accept" the answer. Thanks

Comment: Done. but can u tell me what all devices are supported by this SDK.

Comment: @ icodebuster: i checked it on iPhone 3GS but it's not working as well as it crashed when i'm pressing cancel button.

Comment: oh now it's crashing like anything as soon as i click on the icon n take the camera on top of QR code. it just crashed with this error.


[HomeViewController imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Did you implement the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method

Comment: @Zac24 which version of iOS there in iPhone 3GS you tried

Comment: now it's not crashing but how do i get the info of that QR code. i'm pasting the whole code what i have used in the app. just open the link below n can u you n tell me what all changes i need to make.

http://pastebin.com/Myws4Bmp

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in the comments - use chat for things not directly related to the answer.